# Weird DartEditor behavior / bug?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm working on a little website using dart.
I have one project for the server, and another for the client app (see picture below)

[image: project tree]

In the server app I serve the client app from the client project like this

```
runServer() {
  var staticHandler = createStaticHandler(r"C:\Users\Lukasz\dart\linkShepherdClient\web\", defaultDocument: 'linkShepherd.html',serveFilesOutsidePath: true);
  var handler = new Cascade()
                      .add(staticHandler)
                      .add(routes.handler)
                      .handler;
  io.serve(handler, InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 8080).then((server) {
    print('Listening on port 8080');
  }).catchError((error) => print(error));   
}
```

Everything worked fine. But now the changes I do in the client project stopped affecting the site served by the server (a site still loads, just an older version, with slightly different styling, but most importantly also an older .dart script file). When I run the client directly from it's project everything is up to date.
Opening and closing the editor does not help.
Is the dart editor actually creating some sort of cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache might be from `dart:io`. You should probably launch a `pub serve` instance and redirect to this during development anyway. This way any transformers (Angular, Polymer, ...) are applied as well.
When deployed the server should serve the build output of the client.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer. I couldn't find it in the menu. A simple solution which worked for me, was to mark the "Run>>Always Run Last Launch"

Comment: I don't understand, you couldn't find what (it) in the menu? My answer suggests to not serving Dart source directly from disk to the browser but that Dart source should be served by `pub serve` (you might start an instance manually from command line or from within your custom web server of from your servers launch configuration) and then in your custom web server forward requests to Dart sources to this `pub serve` instance. In production your server should then serve dart2js-output of your client instead of course.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I meant, I could not find `pub serve` in the menu. I think I now know you meant the "Mange Launches" tool in "Run" menu. Unfortunately I still don't know how to set it up, to apply your solution.

Comment: Maybe you need to run `pub upgrade` in the server project to get the changes. Have you tried that?

Comment: I just realized some additional information might have been missing. I think the problems started after I renamed the client. Also when just typing in localhost:8080, and not localhost:8080/linkSheperd.html I get a 404 not found error and the "Tools Output" command window prints `[web] GET / => Could not find asset linkShepherdClient|web.`

Comment: How are those project connected. Do you have a `path` dependency in the server project`

Comment: No there was no path dependency. I added one with `linkShepherdClient: path: C:\Users\Lukasz\dart\linkShepherdClient` but i still get the 404 error and `[web] GET / => Could not find asset linkShepherdClient|web.`

Comment: Can you publish you project at github? Would make it easier to see what you are actually doing and what is missing to make it work.

Comment: https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdServer, I will add the client in a second

Comment: The link for the client app https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdClient

Comment: I checked out your projects. I made two comments in GitHub, I assume you got notifications. Your `bin/linkShepherdServer.dart` file serves Dart source directly. In this case only the browser can prevent that updated content is served. Can you try to do Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page and force the browser to reload it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78045/discussion-between-lukasz-and-gunter-zochbauer).